# Nether Portal won't light?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that this question has been asked before, but I have read the posts and tried everything and it still won't light. I have used 10 obsidian blocks to make a 4x5 portal, not touching any other obsidian. when I try to activate the portal it just sets the obsidian block on fire. any suggestions?

Comment: It might sound stupid, but just to make sure, what are you trying to light it with?

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying in Pocket Edition. Try a nether reactor instead: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Nether_Reactor